# linux/cputime.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu, kernel

При сборке простейшего модуля ядра не может найти cputime.h, хоть он есть (/usr/src/linux-headers-...-generic/include/linux/sched/cputime.h)

Остальные хедеры видит, такие как

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/shed.h>
...
```

собираю sudo make, через root тоже пробовал.

Вот Makefile:

```
obj-m += pidwatcher.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
CURR := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(CURR) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(CURR) clean
```

Comment: А или подождите, вы обращаетесь как `linux/cputime.h`? Он же `linux/sched/cputime.h` вроде

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте явно указать директорию с заголовочными файлами для make, например так:

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/src/linux-headers-...-generic/include" make
```

или через Makefile:

```
INC=-I/usr/src/linux-headers-...-generic/include
```